# I want to use method which contains instance as parameter

Tags: c#

[image]

I am newbie of C#. I want to use method which contains instance as parameter.

```
Class c = new Class();
object.method(c);
```

The full code is here:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ControllerDevice c; // interface
    Judge j;
    FallingRect f;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        c = new Kinect(this); // class implement interface 
        j = new Judge();
        InitializeComponent();
        c.start();
        f = new FallingRect(this, -200);

        /*
         * Question code
         */
        j.doJudge(c.getLeftTop, c.getRightTop, f);
    }
}

interface ControllerDevice
{
    Point getRightTop();
    Point getLeftTop();

    void start();
}
```

Visual studio says **"the method contains invalid parameters"**.

Comment: How you have defined the method ? what is the signature ? Code plz

Comment: is object here same as System.Object? or is it something else?

Comment: I'll get back to you when I can read Japanese.

Comment: Please don't paste an image, paste the code as text.

Comment: you are passing invalid parameter...check out what parameters the method actually take

Comment: did you forget brackets () at c.getLeftTop and c.getRightTop? c.getLeftTop() looks less wrong to me...

Comment: Yes **THAT IS THE ANSWER!** Oh my god... thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide parameters to getLeftTop and getRightTop methods; from the code above you're trying to supply functions themselves as arguments to doJudge method

Based on your last update, you line should be

```
j.doJudge(c.getLeftTop(), c.getRightTop(), f);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass an instance of class as an argument try like this..

```
public void Create(Object c)
{
   Class x = (Class)c; // type cast your class
}
```